# Jasmin HttpConnector for MT

Tags: python, sms-gateway, jasmin-sms

Is there any way to implement http connector for sending messages(MT) in Jasmin? According to documentation jasmin HTTP API supports smpp connector only.

**Update 1:**
More information of scenario:

I have 4 sms providers that I need to implement using Jasmin.
one of them is using SMPP protocol and is working fine with jasmin using smpp connector.
Other 3 have http protocol (call url with params to send SMS).
I want to use http protocol with jasmin to use its routing and other stuff.

Comment: consider adding more information in your question

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working and/or are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Jasmin only supports HTTP client connectors for MO (mobile originated) messages.

Having found myself with the same scenario as yourself, I found the simplest solution was to write an SMPP-to-HTTP service which allows Jasmin to connect to it and relay MT messages via HTTP. Hope that helps

Comment: I did it in different way. Added http MT service inside jasmin by combining stuff from smpp and http. Also created my own broker config for queue management. Its was a pain but it was needed. Thanks for answering

Comment: Nice. Is that using out-of-the-box Jasmin or customized Jasmin? I found I was getting errors when trying to use HTTP client connectors for MT. You should post your solution as an answer here - I'm sure it will get some kudos :)

Comment: Its customized Jasmin, I added the support to create Http MT connectors using the same logic like SMPP, Now if http connector is selected by router it transmits it using http mt queues of rabbitmq

Comment: @WAnjum I appreciate if you post your solution here

Answer (score 0):

Here is the overview for adding Http MT support in Jasmin:

Add connector class and manager for http MT connector

Add router manager

Modify smpp protocol module and detach http mt call from this module before it is dispatched to smpp queue. Detachment will be done after router has selected your custom connector and user balance etc is deducted from user account but before transaction is queued.

By detachment means use your own queue (rabbitmq queue) and and publish your transaction on this. 
Create subscriber for rabbitmq and response back as required.

Using this method will return same message id and responses like smpp.

For more details or help please comment.